Is there a male conception of Shakti?
On the Wikipedia page, it is stated that Shakti/Pure Consciousness is conceived in feminine terms. Is there a male conception of Shakti anywhere?

The Shiva part of Shiva-Shakthi union is considered the male.

@Narasimham Yes, but Shiva is someone separate. Shiva is an ontologically separate entity. I'm asking if within this union (or non-union), there are any conceptions where Shakthi is male.
